# Client side scripting is not working after Response.end() method while downloading zipfiles

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I had problem in my web application,in which on a button click i will bring data from server and  export 2 or 3 datatables to excel files and save it into Temp folder inside my application.

Then using Ionic.Zip dll, i will zip these files and download it to the client machine.Mostly it will take some time to happen.
Problem is that on button click(client side using jquery) i have shown a div which prompts a loader image.later in the server side while downloading files i had use response.end() method.so after that i cant access any of my client side script or function to hide that div which contains loader image.so my loader still shows even after the download complete.

So please help me to hide that div after i have done my downloading.

Answer (score 0):

response.end() throws ThreadAbortException. Are you handling this on server side?

Comment: Response.end() always throw error .i do not know how to avoid that ThreadAbortException there.